# How to render a view from inside of a controller

Tags: scala, playframework

From inside of a controller action I want to render a view, is this possible?

Example:

```
def index: Action {
   val html: String = // render some action here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def index: Action {
   val html: String = views.html.foo().body
}
```

Or

```
def index: Action {
   val html: String = views.html.foo().toString
}
```